# How to make a list from 2 arrays in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two arrays, I want to make a list with its first element as [first element of array one, 'first element of array 2'] and so on.
Basically each elements of a list will be a list.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listb = [a, b, c, d]
```

Desired Output:

```
listc = [1a, 2b, 3c, 4d]
```

Comment: Please include the desired output.

Comment: And a sample of the input

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're describing what `zip` does. Also, it seems from the comments that you want the second element to be a string, so here is how:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> [[e1, str(e2)] for e1, e2 in zip(a, b)]
[[1, '4'], [2, '5'], [3, '6']]
```

Comment: And if I want b to be in single quotes then? like [[1, '4'], [2, '5'], [3, '6']]

Comment: Also, I want each element of a list to be a list

Comment: I don't understand the first comment. The input is two lists of numbers or a list of numbers and a list of strings?

Comment: I think he want `[[e1, str(e2)] for e1, e2 in zip(a, b)]`.  Don't ask me why.

Comment: Updated. And yes, why, oh why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `zip` here. It functions by iterating over the arguments at the same time. You can use it like this:

```
[ [first, str(second)] for first, second in zip(a, b)]
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
list(zip(a, [str(x) for x in b]))
```

That'll give you a list of tuples rather than a list of lists but if you don't mind the immutability, that might be what you want.